# How to change a Kerberos password on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, kerberos

How do you forcefully change a user's Kerberos password in Fedora? The only docs I could find mention `kpasswd <username>`, but this requires the user's current password, which the admin probably won't know. I found some BSD docs that use `k5admin -l`, but this doesn't appear to be available in Fedora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `kadmin`. This is part of the `krb5-workstation` package in Fedora and is installed at`/usr/bin/kadmin`.

You can use `kadmin` interactively or with a preset query.

```
$ kadmin
Authenticating as principal self/admin@DOMAIN.TLD with password.
Password for self/admin@DOMAIN.TLD: 
kadmin:  cpw
usage: change_password [-randkey] [-keepold] [-e keysaltlist] [-pw password] principal
```

`kadmin -q "change_password -pw <newpassword>  <username>"`

Note: If using the MIT libraries, which I believe Fedora does, you will have to set the `admin_server` in the `[realms]` section of `/etc/krb5.conf`. (Your master server must also be running `kadmind` (the kadmin service).

```
[realms]
DOMAIN.TLD = {
    admin_server = krb5kdc-master.domain.tld
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to modify /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl to give my user full admin rights, and then restart the krb5kdc and kadmin services, but otherwise kadmin change_password worked.

Comment: I had to make an slight modification to make work the non interactive version of the command:

kadmin -l cpw -p newpassword username

Comment: @alfredocambera Sounds like you are using `heimdal` rather than `(mit-)krb5`.

Comment: @84104 indeed. I'm pretty new to kerberos and it took me a while to find the correct command. Nevertheless this helped me a lot. Is mit's version better than heimdal's? I'd appreciate your opinion on this.

Comment: I edited in the current location on my Fedora 27 system. I have a CentOS 7 box handy and it's in the same location; what CentOS has it at `/usr/kerberos/sbin/kadmin`?

Comment: @mattdm CentOS 5, which was current at the time of the answer.

Comment: Oh wow. For some reason this got bumped and showed up on my list of recent Fedora questions and I missed the date. In any case, the edit is correct for current Fedora. :)